# vim-latex compilation and viewing

Tags: plugin-vim-latex

I have installed Vim-latex on my Mac. When I compiled my file, there seemed to be no error. Yet, when I pressed \lv, I got the following:

```
Error detected while processing function Tex_ViewLaTeX:
line   34:
E121: Undefined variable: s:viewer
E116: Invalid arguments for function strlen(s:viewer)
line   39:
E121: Undefined variable: appOpt
line   79:
E121: Undefined variable: execString
E116: Invalid arguments for function substitute(execString, '\V$*', mainfname, 'g')
line   80:
E121: Undefined variable: execString
E116: Invalid arguments for function Tex_Debug
line   82:
E121: Undefined variable: execString
```

Besides, for the sake of testing, I added an extra $ sign in my source file, but I got the same result as before when I pressed \ll. Thus, I guess the compilation was actually problematic. Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [this issue](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/issues/122) that was recently fixed.

Comment: @Ralf it was fixed 1 year ago if I read right. OP would need a pretty old version of the plugin to get that error. Can OP confirm version/whether or not updating works.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Ahh - yes, it's 2019 now :-)

Comment: @Ralf ah so the commit actually is recent? The “about 1 year ago” tripped me up. I wish it would display the actual date.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble No, I just saw Jan 31 and didn't check the year. But also the last official release on the github page is from 2018-01-12.   As you said, the OP should use most recent version.